# string creations with variables in javascript, html or asp user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Whenever i have to create some html where i needs to include some variables in between, i generally gets stuck spending lot of time and then by hit and trial gets some working solution. But i believe, i don't understand the actual technique behind as i somehow gets solution and leave carelessly. Can somebody guide towards a technical understanding for doing this.
Here is one of the string i have somehow created and also working(created in ascx control of asp.net) :

- Create anchor tag :

  ```
  <a style='<%# "background-image: url(&#39;" + Eval("url") + "&#39;)&#59;" %>' id="ancrTag" href='<%# Eval("link") %>' runat="server"><%# Eval("name") %></a>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to do this. The beauty of asp.net is that you can set these things from the code behind.

Say

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" id="hy1" />
```

---

```
hy1.Text = "Click me";
hy1.NavigateUrl = "www.google.com";
```

You get the idea.

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/code-behind/

Comment: I also knows that. But i needs to learn what i mentioned.That is the reason i put this question here. what if i have to set some string in javascript. how will i do that. if you have some technical resource for these kind of string manipulations then plz guide.